# reading posted values in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, http, post

I'm going to create a post test server, something like:
http://www.posttestserver.com/

I'm using a hardware device to send remote data to my system via HTTP post, then I want to receive the posted data, I've tested several methods to read data posted from this device but I had no luck. But the site mentioned above could get data posted by device, here is the code I've used to get posted data:

```
            System.Text.StringBuilder displayValues =
            new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
            postedValues = Request.Form;
        String nextKey;
        Response.Write(postedValues.AllKeys.Length.ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < postedValues.AllKeys.Length; i++)
        {
            nextKey = postedValues.AllKeys[i];
            if (nextKey.Substring(0, 2) != "__")
            {
                displayValues.Append("<br>");
                displayValues.Append(nextKey);
                displayValues.Append(" = ");
                displayValues.Append(postedValues[i]);
            }
        }
```

what is going wrong? I set my page url in device and then try to post data, but I get nothing

Answer (score 1):

Are you posting to the correct page, can you attach to IIS process and put a break point?
You can also use a http://fiddler2.com/ tool to see what kind of post is generated.

Your code looks fine, does the Response.Write(postedValues.AllKeys.Length.ToString()); display anything or simply 0?

Comment: how about other questions, are you connecting to you local machine, so you can attach debugger? if not, can you run fiddler on the remote machine and post what it actually receives?